# To join comma separated in string

Tags: c#

In the below code i want the string value to be comma separated but it produces the result like testtest1test2 .But i want to display like test,test1,test2.Pls help me.

```
    string Save=string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
//i=0 test ,i=1 test1....
         Save += nFIleUpload.OrgFileName;// display  value like testtest1test2..
    }
    string s = string.Join(",", Save);
```

Comment: Something is wrong with nFIleUpload.OrigFileName

Comment: add the values to a List<string> and it will be easier.. change sting Save = string.Empty to `var Save = new List<string>();` then add the values of nFileUpload.OrgFileName to the list..

Comment: If `nFIleUpload.OrgFileName` is `"testtest1test2"`, how do you know where to put the commas? Where does `OrgFileName` come from?

Comment: @Blorgbeard it is a loop on i=0 it test 1=1 test1...

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth check my edited question

Comment: common sense should tell you that this line would never work 
`Save += nFIleUpload.OrgFileName;` when trying `to join("," Save);`

Comment: Your code won't even compile. You are passing a string as the second parameter to string.Join when it requires a collection. If you were to just pass a string then the Join method wouldn't know where one item ended and the next item started so it wouldn't know where to put the join character/string.

Comment: Isn't `nFIleUpload.OrgFileName` going to be the same value every time? Anyway.. just change `Save` to be a `List<string>` instead of `string`, and do `Save.Add(nFIleUpload.OrgFileName);` in the loop.

Comment: @user4779701 when posting code you need to post all relevant code.. also use the debugger.. I am curious how you are loading multiple filenames inot the `nFileUpload` object.. in the meantime you could have saved yourself a lot of headache by googling the `string.Join()` function as well

Comment: Why you  don't add `Save += ",";` simply after `Save += nFIleUpload.OrgFileName;` ?? I think your issue will resolved in this way!

Answer (score 2):

Change this code

```
string Save=string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
     Save += nFIleUpload.OrgFileName;// display  value like testtest1test2..
}
string s = string.Join(",", Save);
```

to the following

```
var Save = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
     Save.Add(nFIleUpload.OrgFileName);// display  value like testtest1test2..
}
var s = string.Join(",", Save);
```

Answer (score 1):

And to go off of MethodMan's answer, when you get tired of seeing the same value added to Save for each iteration, make sure to use that index.

```
var Save = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    Save.Add(nFIleUpload[i].OrgFileName);// display  value like testtest1test2..
}
var s = string.Join(",", Save);
```

If nFIleUpload is actually the variable that holds the strings.. is it the files variable? Who watches the watchmen? These are the questions to ask..

Comment: touche @mike, touche.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using an array, for sample:

```
string[] save = new string[files.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
   save[i] = nFIleUpload.OrgFileName;

// join all values
string s = string.Join(",", save);
```

Or use a `stringBulder` which is better to concat strings, for sample:

```
// define the stringBuilder
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

// define the loop to concat all values separated by ',' comma
for (var i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    text.AppendFormat("{0},", nFIleUpload.OrgFileName);

// get the output
string s = text.ToString();

// remove the last comma if necessary
if (s.EndsWith(","))
    s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1);
```